# Unable to attach SQL Server CE 3.5 database to LLBLGen Pro

Tags: sql-server-ce, ssms, llblgenpro, llblgen

I have the `.sdf` for SQL Server Compact Edition database of Northwind, I'm trying to attach it to llblgen pro but it refuses to connect, in the 'database drivers' drop down I've selected SQL Server 2000/etc, etc (there is no SQL Server CE in the drop down) and in 'server name' I've put the full path to the database:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact
>   Edition\v3.5\Samples\Northwind.sdf

The error I get when I try to test the connection is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)
>
> LLBLGen Pro version 3.5. Build March 23rd, 2012
>   -----[Core exception]--------------------    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean
>   ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean
>   trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64
>   timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String
>   host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   Int64 timerStart)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String
>   newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
>   String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) 
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   SD.LLBLGen.Pro.Gui.Controls.WizardPages.MetaDataRetrievalWizard_Step_ConnectionData.TestConnectionData(Boolean
>   showSuccess)

I've also tried adding the sdf to sql server management studio then adding it to llblgen but still no luck...

Comment: SQL Server CE is **NOT** the same as the "regular" SQL Server. If you don't have any "SQL Server CE" entry in the dropdown, you won't be able to connect.

Comment: how can I get SQL CE in the drop down?

Comment: When I Google for "LLBLGen SQL Server CE", [this is the first link that comes up](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/2.6/compactframeworksupport.htm) - have you had a look at that?? If that doesn't help --> ask LLBLGen Support...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the version of LLBLGen Pro I was using does not support .Net Compact Framework (as of V3.0 the stopped supporting it).

Answer (score 1):

LLBLGen supports SQL CE database. Please specify the correct compatibility level in .config file:

<add key="SqlServerDQECompatibilityLevel" value="4" />

Please read "DQE Compatibility mode" section in the documentation:
http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/3.5/LLBLGen%20Pro%20RTF/Using%20the%20generated%20code/gencode_applicationconfiguration.htm#compatibilitymodesqlserver